# XML Deserialization : Same element name but different type

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I have 2 different type of xml files that needs to be serialize using single class.
I cannot use the xml parser before serializing. This is typical deserialization scenario of MSMQ.

The problem is with message_string node in xml provided.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tms_msg>
 <transaction>
  <message_string>
     <latitude>latitidue valeu</latitude>
     <longitude>longitude</longitude>
  </message_string>
 </transaction>
</tms_msg>
```

and type 2

```
<tms_msg>
 <transaction>
  <message_string>message string</message_string>
 </transaction>
</tms_msg>
```

The classes used to deserialize are

```
public class transaction
{
    [XmlElement("message_string", typeof(Complextype))]
    public object[] StringsAndInts;

    [XmlElement("message_string", typeof(string))]
    public string stringValue;
}

[XmlRoot("tms_msg")]
public class tms_msg
{
    [XmlElement("transaction")]
    public transaction transaction;
}
public class Complextype
{
    public string latitude;
    public string longitude;
}
```

Implementation Part

```
 public class Program
{
    public Object CreateObject(string XMLString, Object YourClassObject)
    {
        XmlSerializer oXmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(YourClassObject.GetType());

        //The StringReader will be the stream holder for the existing XML file

        YourClassObject = oXmlSerializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(XMLString));

        //initially deserialized, the data is represented by an object without a defined type

        return YourClassObject;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        tms_msg objempq = new tms_msg();
        objempq = (tms_msg)CreateObject(txtXML.Text, objempq);
    }
}
```

Please do not provide suggestion of xml parsing and finding the element type.

Comment: Just add following to Complextype : [XmlText]
        public String Text { get; set; }
You can still deserialize without the string.

Comment: Have you got a solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

```
[XmlRoot("tms_msg")]
    public class TmsMessage
    {
        [XmlElement("transaction")]
        public Transaction Transaction;
    }

    public class Transaction
    {
        [XmlElement("message_string", typeof(ComplexType))]
        public ComplexType[] ComplexObjects { get; set; }
    }

    public class ComplexType
    {
        [XmlElement("latitue")]
        public string Latitude { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("longitude")]
        public string Longitude { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public String Text { get; set; }

        //in other part of source code of this class, check the object type.
        //if it's type1 then property Text gets null; if it's type 2, property 
        //Latitude and Longitude get null.
    }
```

Comment: i donot think this would be possible to meet my requirement. We cannot make all object as CompleType

Answer (score 1):

Read `message string` from `Text` property:

```
    [Serializable]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public class tms_msg
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("transaction")]
        public tms_msgTransaction[] transaction { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public class tms_msgTransaction
    {
        public tms_msgTransactionMessage_string message_string { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public class tms_msgTransactionMessage_string
    {
        public string latitude { get; set; }

        public string longitude { get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        public string[] Text { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: i donot think this would be possible to meet my requirement. We cannot make all object as CompleType